# Drush crashes after "command dispatch complete"

Tags: drush

I have a custom drush script.
This script loads, changes and saves ~10000 drupal commerce products.

After that I get the message

```
Command dispatch complete [1140.43 sec, 663.25 МБ]                                                                                                                                                                                 [notice]
 Timer                Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page                 1140.368   1      1140367.61 
 drupal_http_request  67.66      1032   65.562 
Peak memory usage was 784.48 МБ [1140.43 sec, 663.24 МБ]
```

And AFTER that script hangs and consumes more and more memory.
Finally, after long time, script reaches 1.5 G memory limit and dies.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 80 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.ru/htdocs/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc on line 302

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 80 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.ru/htdocs/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc on line 302
```

All products which were processed by the script are sucessfully changed.

The question: why drush script hangs when dispatch is complete and what it makes for such a long time when all products are processed?
Is it sort of a post-processing?

Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why my script hangs after "Command dispatch complete".

The matter is that I have installed the "Search API" module.
This module has

```
function search_api_track_item_change($type, array $item_ids)
```

method. In this method it calls **search_api_index_specific_items_delayed** function, and in this function it registers shutdown function **_search_api_index_queued_items**.

```
drupal_register_shutdown_function('_search_api_index_queued_items');
```

**_search_api_index_queued_items** function calls **search_api_index_specific_items** and finally in this function search api loads into memory all changed products! (~10000)

```
function search_api_index_specific_items(SearchApiIndex $index, array $ids) {
    $items = $index->loadItems($ids);
    // Clone items because data alterations may alter them.
    $cloned_items = array();
    foreach ($items as $id => $item) {
    $cloned_items[$id] = clone $item;
    }
    $indexed = $items ? $index->index($cloned_items) : array();
    ...
```

And it happens not just one time, but several times for every index of my drupal installation.

Of cause I have not enough memory for 10000 products, so script dies.

**My solution**: I just disabled "Index items immediately" option in my search api indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Drush is running out of memory.

In the case of re/indexing search data via [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), the item in that issue queue for this is [Better memory usage on indexing](https://www.drupal.org/node/1137734).

To work around these sorts of issues, you can increase the amount of memory used by Drush, without touching the memory limit used by your Web server.  See [Configuring php.ini](http://www.drush.org/en/master/configure/#configuring-phpini) for details.

In my case, in my drush.ini, I increased it from:

- memory_limit = 256M

to:

- memory_limit = 512M

...and it solved my Search API (re)indexing problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you see code inside drush.php file ...

```
function drush_main() {
  $return = '';
  // Start code coverage collection.
  if ($coverage_file = drush_get_option('drush-coverage', FALSE)) {
    drush_set_context('DRUSH_CODE_COVERAGE', $coverage_file);
    xdebug_start_code_coverage(XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED | XDEBUG_CC_DEAD_CODE);
    register_shutdown_function('drush_coverage_shutdown');
  }

  if ($file = drush_get_option('early', FALSE)) {
    require_once $file;
    $function = 'drush_early_' . basename($file, '.inc');
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      if ($return = $function()) {
        // If the function returns FALSE, we continue and attempt to bootstrap
        // as normal. Otherwise, we exit early with the returned output.
        if ($return === TRUE) {
          $return = '';
        }
        drush_bootstrap_finish();
        return $return;
      }
    }
  }

  // Process initial global options such as --debug.
  _drush_bootstrap_global_options();

  $return = '';
  drush_bootstrap_to_phase(DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUSH);
  if (!drush_get_error()) {
    // Do any necessary preprocessing operations on the command,
    // perhaps handling immediately.
    $command_handled = drush_preflight_command_dispatch();
    if (!$command_handled) {
      $return = _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch();
    }
  }
  drush_bootstrap_finish();

  // After this point the drush_shutdown function will run,
  // exiting with the correct exit code.
  return $return;
}
```

Seems like everything goes smooth till

```
$return = _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch();
```

where it logs

```
drush_log(dt('Peak memory usage was !peak', array('!peak' => drush_format_size(memory_get_peak_usage()))), 'memory');
```

So, A good starting point for you to debug is analyse below functions with log statements

```
  drush_bootstrap_finish();
  drush_shutdown(); // In includes/bootstrap.inc
```

Comment: Thank you, Anil Sagar! I decided not to explore drush spaghetti code, but use exit() function on the end of my script instead. It works, but I have one problem: if I use exit() in drush code, I got "Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error" message. The question: how can I exit from Drush immediately without errors? Where should I look for an answer to this question?